# SQL and Normalization

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

It's a design decision that I'd like some advice with really. I'm attempting to record
employees' staff breaks. Also, employees may take many breaks in any one given day. What tactics should I employ?

My thoughts originally were an employee may take many breaks and a single break would be for one employee. One to many.

However, it's also possible (in theory) for an employee to take many breaks and a single break
being taken by many employees - many-to-many. For instance John and Fred take a break at 12.00pm say and return at 1.00pm.

We get down to splitting hairs though with me inclined to go for the one-to-many. For instance John goes on a break at 12.01pm say, Fred leaves at 12.00pm with them both returning at different time slots, 1.05pm and 1.03pm say.

Can you offer some good database design practices for this type of scenario? Ideas in pictures below:

[many to many](http://acookson.org/testdir/many-to-many.png)
[one to many](http://acookson.org/testdir/one-many.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go for the one-to-many. Definitely

You can add a "standard break" table, where you can store standard values like '12 to 1' for lunch break. When an employee (or group of employees) take one of these "standard breaks", coresponding "breaks" lines are added to the "breaks" table.

Eventually, in a more complex model, this "standard break" table is linked with a "default schedule" table, where, for example, office employees benefit from a "lunch break".

Your tables could look like that:

```
Tbl_Break:
    id_Break (primary key)
    id_Employee (not null)
    breakStartTime (not null)
    breakEndTime (not null)        
    id_StandardBreak (nullable)

Tbl_StandardBreak:
    id_StandardBreak (primary key)
    standardBreakStartTime (not null)
    standardBreakEndTime (not null)
    standardBreakDescription (not null)
    id_Schedule (not null)
```

In this configuration, you will either manage the one-to-many relation between employees and breaks, or the more complex many-to-many relation between employees and default breaks, depending if the value of field Tbl_Break.id_StandardBreak is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would recoment one-to-many approach. Once you have the data in the db you can analyze them and figure out who took a break with who.

Also, since you probably have punchcards or something like that to automate the whole process, one-to-many is the way you want to go.